# How can i add class to specific <td> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to change cell style during editing from menu button like spreadsheet.below code is not working properly.

```
$("#tab1 tr td:not(:first-child)").on("click", function (e) {          
    console.log(e);
    if(e.currentTarget.contentEditable != null){
         $(e.currentTarget).attr("contentEditable",true);
     }
     else{
         $(e.currentTarget).append("<input type='text'>");
     }
});
//Add bold text
$("#tab1 tr td:not(:first-child)").on("click", function () { 
   var mytd=this;
   $("#btn4 li a:eq(0)").on("click",function() {
     $(mytd).toggleClass("bold");
     $(this).toggleClass("bg");
   });
});
```

Take a look at second part of code.it is not making current cell bold.it is making bold previous or anyother cell value bold.

Comment: on click inside an on click? is that correct in your html?

Comment: Define "not working".  What _is_ the code doing?  Do the jQuery selectors find the element(s) you're looking for?  If not, what do they find?  At what point and in what way does the observed behavior deviate from the expected behavior?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the function binding to #btn4 inside your click? Simply removing that part makes it work as I would expect it to, but I assumed there's a reason why that code is there.

Comment: I have written above i am changing style of text during editing table through menu button like spreadsheet.